# sonarqube store results in database takes way too long

Tags: mysql, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube is taking very long time, around 40 to 50 minutes to transfer sonar result to the sonarqube mySQL database.

**Jenkins logs:**

```
06:44:33.974 INFO  - Execute decorators...
06:47:01.532 INFO  - Store results in database
07:26:44.253 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://....
```

**build.gradle** :

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}
```

**gradle.properties**:

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=https://myhost/prod
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myhost:port/sonar_prod?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.username=user
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.password= somepassword
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, problem was with my jdbc configuration. Changing it did the trick.

> `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myHost:port/sonar_prod?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&connectTimeout=0&socketTimeout=0&autoReconnect=true`

Answer (score 0):

There is too little information here to diagnose your problem. However, there's plenty to suggest a solution: upgrade your version of SonarQube.

5.6 is the new LTS, and among other things, it removes all direct communication between the scanner and the database. The fact that you still have this step in your analysis tells me you're on a rather old version, and could stand to upgrade.

Comment: Well, I can't upgrade. It is what my origination is having right now and they take their own sweet time in testing a new version before upgrading to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myHost:port/sonar_prod?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&connectTimeout=0&socketTimeout=0&autoReconnect=true
```

This option helped for me